# Sum filtered items/images

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a filter with checkboxes using Shuffle.js, just after filtering want to count/sum filtered items using filtered items .length(), and update a div with this value. For the reason I don't get the calculation is wrong.
Here what Im trying :

```
 var _checkbox = $(".buttons input");
     _checkbox.on('change', function(){
     
        var countThis = $(this).val(),
            total = 0;
        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){ 
            var shuffleItems = $('.image[data-gallery="'+countThis+'"]').length;
            total += isNaN(parseInt(shuffleItems)) ? 0 : parseInt(shuffleItems);
            //total += shuffleItems;
           // total = parseInt(total) + (parseInt(shuffleItems) || 0);
        });

       console.log(total);
      $('.nr-filtered').text(total);
    });
```

here a pen of more details : (https://codepen.io/testeristesting/pen/oNeaZYm)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have something to do with the way the filtering is working and that you're not checking for the `visibility` of the elements.

Here's a slightly different approach that looks to be showing the correct number.

First - get a list of all the checked values.  Then count all `.image` elements that are visible whose `gallery` value is included in the checked values.

```
  var total = 0;
  var checks = $('input:checked').toArray().map((el) => $(el).val());
  var numShowing = $('.image[data-gallery]:visible').toArray().filter((el) => {
    var val = $(el).data('gallery');
    return checks.includes(val);
  }).length

  $('.nr-filtered').text(numShowing);
```

Comment: Well thanks for your time, I tired you js, the result is always 0, I dont think it has something with visibility, how about if all are visible ?

But in any case thanks,